# Pieces knocked over in blitz chess

Tags: blitz

In blitz (lightning) chess: If my opponent knocks over a piece when moving then presses his clock before replacing the piece is this illegal? If so do I stop the clock and call the DOP?

Answer (score 3):

According to FIDE Handbook:

> Article 7: Irregularities
>
> 7.4
>
> If a player displaces one or more pieces, he shall re-establish the
>   correct position in his own time. If necessary, either the player or
>   his opponent shall stop the chessclock and ask for the arbiter’s
>   assistance. The arbiter may penalise the player who displaced the
>   pieces.

That means, yes, you can stop the clock and call the arbiter for your assistance if he did not adjust the pieces in his own time.